# Access array key value without specifying the key

Tags: php, arrays

I have:

```
public $staticRoutes = array(
        'dog-toys' => 'Index',
        ) ;

if(array_key_exists($controller, $this->staticRoutes))
{
    $controller = new $controller ;
}
```

The new $controller is becoming 'dog-toys', which is not what I want.

How can I change what I have so that `$controller = new Index ;` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some variation of:

```
$controller = new ${staticRoutes[$controller]} ;
```

I cannot test it right now, so to be safe you could also do:

```
$ctrl = $staticRoutes[$controller];
$controller = new $ctrl;
```

Comment: OP - This works because your array is what's known as an associative array. Your `$controller` variable is actually referencing the key of that array, so you can access the value the same way you would with an indexed (numbered) array - `array[key]`.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to actually use you `$staticRoutes` array like this:

```
$controller_instance = new $this->staticRoutes[$controller];
```

Note I changed the name of the variable you are assigning to for clarity's sake. I am also assuming that the code trying to instantiate this controller is in the same class (or inheriting class) where the `$staticRoutes` property is defined (thus the use of `$this`).